# Find div which does not contain a specific property under specific attribute using CSS selector

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have the following situation:

```
<div id="foo">
   <div id="1" style="transform:translate3d(5px,5px,5px);"></div>
   <div id="2" style="background-color:black;"></div>
</div>
```

I want to find the div that does not have the 'transform' property i.e div with 'id = 2'.

I have tried the following, but it only selects the div having transform property, I want the exact opposite.

```
$('#foo').find('div[style*="transform"]');
```

Comment: Could you please give me a demonstration, may be plunker / jsfiddle ?

Comment: I gave an answer using `:not()`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```js
$('#foo').find('div:not([style*="transform"])').css('color','red')
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="foo">
   <div id="1" style="transform:translate3d(5px,5px,5px);">1</div>
   <div id="2" style="background-color:black;">2</div>
</div>
```

1. Use `:not()`

Comment: up for u, that was fast!

Answer (score 3):

this well do it

```
$('#foo div').not('div[style*="transform"]');
```

Answer (score 2):

```js
console.log($('#foo').find('div:not([style*="transform"])').text());
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<div id="foo">
  <div id="1" style="transform:translate3d(5px,5px,5px);">111</div>
  <div id="2" style="background-color:black;">222</div>
</div>
```